# How to implement "Please Wait" screen in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, loading, splash-screen, pleasewait

I have developed a Silverlight application. It has a button and once it is clicked the application starts doing something which takes time. Since everything in Silverlight is asynchronous the UI is not lagging, however, I would like to add some animation to it or something else to indicate that the application is actually doing some work and that the user should wait.

I don't know how to implement this, neither thread nor XAML wise. What is the best approach to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Silverlight 4 wait/spinner control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651235/silverlight-4-wait-spinner-control)

Or if you are using MVVM

[Generally Preferred Method for a 'Wait' Screen using MVVM and Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084510/generally-preferred-method-for-a-wait-screen-using-mvvm-and-silverlight)

You can get the busy indicator control out of the Silverlight Toolkit:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. Those links are enough to get started.